# Optional fields in the form. How to assign false instead of error?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, onsubmit

I ran into an interesting problem.
I have a form with optional fields. On submit I get an error trying to assign an empty field to a variable. I want to assign false if the field is empty. How to do it right? Writing multiple ifs seems like a crazy idea to me.

```
`async function submit(e) {
    const name = e.target.name.value
    const adress = e.target.adress.value
    const comment = e.target.comment.value
}`
```

i tried like this but still getting error

```
`async function submit(e) {
    const name = e.target.name.value || false
    const adress = e.target.adress.value || false
    const comment = e.target.comment.value || false
}`
```

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')**

Comment: your solution is good, you just need to add a check for undefined on the input value, for example: e.target?.name?.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that either `name`, `address` or `comment` is `undefined`.

You can get arround this with optional chaining and nullish coalescing (`??`):

```js
async function submit(e) {
    const name = e.target.name?.value ?? false
    const adress = e.target.adress?.value ?? false
    const comment = e.target.comment?.value ?? false
}
```

If you use older versions of JavaScript, which doesn't support the mentionend features above, you have to use a more verbose syntax:

```js
async function submit(e) {
    const name = e.target.name && (e.target.name.value || false)
    const adress = e.target.adress && (e.target.address.value || false)
    const comment = e.target.comment && (e.target.comment.value || false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can use a conditional ternary operator or nullish coalescing. like this example below:

```
//Example using: a conditional ternary operator method 
//Syntax: condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse
//Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

async function submit(e) {
    const name = e.target.name?.value ? e.target.name?.value : false;
    const address = e.target.address?.value ? e.target.address?.value : false;
    const comment = e.target.comment?.value ? e.target.comment?.value : false;
}


//Example using: nullish coalescing method
//Syntax: leftExpr ?? rightExpr
//Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing

async function submit(e) {
    const name = e.target.name?.value ?? false;
    const address= e.target.address?.value ?? false;
    const comment = e.target.comment?.value ?? false;
}
```